# How to remove table format in exported excel using .net

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Currently I am using closedxml.excel to create my excel workbook with multiple excel sheets, however it also helps to create "Table Format" function in each excel sheet at the same time, which prohibits me from copying or moving multiple excel sheets to another new excel workbook all at once.

In order to copy and move multiple excel sheets to another excel sheet all at once, I have to create the excel workbook without any formatting in the data table.

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    type = "none";
    Boolean checks = true;
    String errormsg = "";
    int fromYear = 1;
    int fromMonth = 1;
    int toYear = 1;
    int toMonth = 1;
    int toDay = 1;
    DateTime fromdate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
    DateTime todate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);

    ArrayList accTemp = new ArrayList();
    //check for selected account
    if (cbacc1.Checked == true)
    {
        accTemp.Add("I");
    }
    if (cbacc2.Checked == true)
    {
        accTemp.Add("II");
    }
    if (cbacc3.Checked == true)
    {
        accTemp.Add("III");
    }
    if (cbacc4.Checked == true)
    {
        accTemp.Add("IV");
    }
    acc = accTemp;
    if (accTemp.Count == 0)
    {
        checks = false;
        errormsg = "Please select an account";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('" + errormsg + "');", true);
    }
    try
    {
        //Retrieve From date from text and store as datetime
        fromYear = Convert.ToInt32(fromDateyear.Text);
        fromMonth = Convert.ToInt32(fromDatemonth.Text);
        fromdate = new DateTime(fromYear, fromMonth, 1);

        //Retrieve To date from text and store as datetime
        toYear = Convert.ToInt32(toDateyear.Text);
        toMonth = Convert.ToInt32(toDatemonth.Text);
        todate = new DateTime(toYear, toMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(toYear, toMonth));

    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException es)
    {
        checks = false;
        errormsg = "Please enter correct date";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('" + errormsg + "');", true);
    }
    catch (FormatException es)
    {
        checks = false;
        errormsg = "Please enter Date";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('" + errormsg + "');", true);
    }

    int monthdiff = 0;



    //Get number of month
    if (toYear == fromYear)
    {
        monthdiff = toMonth - fromMonth;
        if (toMonth == 2)
        {
            if (toDay >= 28)
            {
                monthdiff = monthdiff + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (toMonth == 1 || toMonth == 3 || toMonth == 5 || toMonth == 7 || toMonth == 8 || toMonth == 10 || toMonth == 12)
        {
            if (toDay >= 31)
            {
                monthdiff = monthdiff + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (toMonth == 4 || toMonth == 6 || toMonth == 9 || toMonth == 11)
        {
            if (toDay >= 30)
            {
                monthdiff = monthdiff + 1;
            }
        }

    }
    else if (toYear > fromYear)
    {
        monthdiff = 12 - fromMonth;
        monthdiff = monthdiff + toMonth;
        if (toYear - fromYear == 1)
        {
        }
        else if (toYear - fromYear > 1)
        {
            int yeardiff = toYear - fromYear;
            monthdiff += 12 * (yeardiff - 1);
        }
    }

    // check for valid Date
    if (fromdate.Year < 2009 || todate.Year < 2009)
    {
        checks = false;
        errormsg = "Invalid Date";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('" + errormsg + "');", true);
    }
    if (fromdate.Date > todate.Date)
    {
        checks = false;
        errormsg = "From Date cannot be greater than To Date";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('" + errormsg + "');", true);
    }
    int selectedCounts = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Count(li => li.Selected);
    if (selectedCounts == 0)
    {
        checks = false;
        errormsg = "Please select factor";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction('" + errormsg + "');", true);
    }

    if (checks == true)
    {
        //DateArray and PreDate Array are used to store date as date format. Shall be use for tradeDate and SetlDate
        preDateArray = new DateTime[monthdiff + 1];
        DateArray = new DateTime[monthdiff + 1];
        DateTime preDA = new DateTime(fromYear, fromMonth, DateTime.DaysInMonth(fromYear, fromMonth));
        DateTime time = preDA.AddMonths(-1);
        int months = time.Month;
        int years = time.Year;
        preDateArray[0] = new DateTime(years, months, DateTime.DaysInMonth(years, months));

        for (int i = 0; i < monthdiff; i++)
        {

            DateTime times = preDA.AddMonths(i);
            int day = times.Day;
            int month = times.Month;
            int year = times.Year;
            DateTime tests = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
            preDateArray[i + 1] = tests;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < monthdiff + 1; i++)
        {
            DateTime times = preDA.AddMonths(i);
            int day = times.Day;
            int month = times.Month;
            int year = times.Year;
            DateTime tests = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
            DateArray[i] = tests;
        }

        //DateList and PreDateList are used to store date as String format. shall be use for portfolioAsAt and UploadFrom/toDate
        DateList = new String[monthdiff + 1];
        PreDateList = new String[monthdiff + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < DateArray.Length; i++)
        {
            DateList[i] = (DateArray[i]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            PreDateList[i] = (preDateArray[i]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");

        }

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ConvertType = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        }

        List<Attribute_2f> result;
        //HiddenField value store the CheckBoxs values
        String cbattr = HiddenField1.Value;
        //Split the String Value in to String Array
        String[] cbattr1 = cbattr.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();

        //Store as ArrayList
        ArrayList ha = new ArrayList();
        foreach (String attrc in cbattr1)
        {
            ha.Add(attrc);
        }
        result = Attribute_2f.getInfo(ha, acc, preDateArray, DateArray, PreDateList, DateList, ConvertType, "none", null);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        String facc = "";
        foreach (String attrc in cbattr1)
        {
            ha.Add(attrc);
        }

        ArrayList clickfactor1 = new ArrayList();
        Attribute_2f clickfactor = new Attribute_2f();
        List<Attribute_2f> fac = null;
        int y = 0;
        int p = 0;
        //int c = 0;
        fac = Attribute_2f.getFactors(acc, DateList, ha, PreDateList, "none");
        foreach (Attribute_2f factemp in fac)
        {
            clickfactor.setFactor("'" + "'" + factemp.getFactor() + "'" + "'");
            clickfactor.setFactor2("'" + "'" + factemp.getFactor2() + "'" + "'");
            clickfactor.setFactor3("'" + "'" + factemp.getFactor3() + "'" + "'");
            clickfactor.setFactor4("'" + "'" + factemp.getFactor4() + "'" + "'");
            clickfactor1.Add(clickfactor);

            if (cbattr1.Count() == 1)
            {
                facc = factemp.getFactor().ToString();
            }
            if (cbattr1.Count() == 2)
            {
                facc = factemp.getFactor().ToString() + ", " + factemp.getFactor2().ToString();
            }
            if (cbattr1.Count() == 3)
            {
                facc = factemp.getFactor().ToString() + ", " + factemp.getFactor2().ToString() + ", " + factemp.getFactor3().ToString();
            }
            if (cbattr1.Count() == 4)
            {
                facc = factemp.getFactor().ToString() + ", " + factemp.getFactor2().ToString() + ", " + factemp.getFactor3().ToString() + ", " + factemp.getFactor4().ToString();
            }
            if (facc.Contains("ILS (Insurance Linked Security)"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("ILS (Insurance Linked Security)", "ILS");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SFR (Single Family Rental)"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SFR (Single Family Rental)", "SFR");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Retail & Business Products"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Retail & Business Products", "R&B Products");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Construction & Homebuilding"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Construction & Homebuilding", "Constr & Home");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Leisure, Lodging & Entertainment"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Leisure, Lodging & Entertainment", "Leisure");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Latin America"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Latin America", "LATAM");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("North America"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("North America", "NA");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Middle East & Africa"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Middle East & Africa", "ME & A");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Commercial ABS"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Commercial ABS", "ABS");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Russia & CIS"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Russia & CIS", "RU&CIS");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Russia & CIS"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Russia & CIS", "RU&CIS");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Central & Eastern Europe"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Central & Eastern Europe", "CEE");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Aerospace & Defense"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Aerospace & Defense", "Aero");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Agricultural Products"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Agricultural Products", "Agri Prod");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Consumer Products"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Consumer Products", "Consumer Prod");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Sovereign & Public Finance"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Sovereign & Public Finance", "Sovereign");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("Media & Publishing"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("Media & Publishing", "Media");
            }

            if (facc.Contains("AUSTRALIA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("AUSTRALIA", "AU");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("BERMUDA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("BERMUDA", "BM");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("BRITAIN"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("BRITAIN", "GBR");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("BRAZIL"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("BRAZIL", "BR");
            }

            if (facc.Contains("CANADA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("CANADA", "CA");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("CHINA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("CHINA", "CN");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("CROATIA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("CROATIA", "CR");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("DENMARK"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("DENMARK", "DK");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("FINLAND"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("FINLAND", "FI");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("FRANCE"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("FRANCE", "FR");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("GERMANY"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("GERMANY", "GE");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("HONG KONG"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("HONG KONG", "HK");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("HUNGARY"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("HUNGARY", "");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("INDIA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("INDIA", "IN");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("INDONESIA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("INDONESIA", "ID");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("IRELAND"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("IRELAND", "IE");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("ITALY"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("ITALY", "IT");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("JAPAN"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("JAPAN", "JP");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("KUWAIT"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("KUWAIT", "KW");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("LUXEMBOURG"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("LUXEMBOURG", "LU");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("MEXICO"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("MEXICO", "MX");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("NETHERLANDS"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("NETHERLANDS", "NE");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("NORWAY"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("NORWAY", "NO");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("OMAN"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("OMAN", "OM");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("PERU"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("PERU", "PE");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("PHILIPPINES"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("PHILIPPINES", "PH");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("PORTUGAL"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("PORTUGAL", "PT");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("RUSSIA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("RUSSIA", "RU");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SINGAPORE"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SINGAPORE", "SG");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SOUTH KOREA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SOUTH KOREA", "KR");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SPAIN"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SPAIN", "SP");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SRI LANKA"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SRI LANKA", "SR");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SWEDEN"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SWEDEN", "SE");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("SWITZERLAND"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("SWITZERLAND", "SW");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("THAILAND"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("THAILAND", "TH");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("UNITED STATES"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("UNITED STATES", "US");
            }
            if (facc.Contains("WESTERN EUROPE"))
            {
                facc = facc.Replace("WESTERN EUROPE", "WE");
            }

            if (facc.Contains("("))
            {
                string regex = "(\\[.*\\])|(\".*\")|('.*')|(\\(.*\\))";
                facc = Regex.Replace(facc, regex, "");

            }
            // DataTable dt = new DataTable(facc);
            var dt = new DataTable(facc);




            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Market Value");
            dt.Columns.Add("Interest Accrued");
            dt.Columns.Add("GainLoss");
            dt.Columns.Add("CashFlow");
            dt.Columns.Add("EOP Weightage");
            dt.Columns.Add("BOP Weightage");
            dt.Columns.Add("Return");
            dt.Columns.Add("Cum_Return");
            dt.Columns.Add("Contribution");
            dt.Columns.Add("Cum_contribution");
            dt.Columns.Add("annualised");
            dt.Columns.Add("premarket");
            dt.Columns.Add("preinterest");
            dt.Columns.Add("inflow");
            dt.Columns.Add("gainlost");

            List<Attribute_2f> returnlist = Attribute_2f.getInfo(ha, acc, preDateArray, DateArray, PreDateList, DateList, ConvertType, "Monthly", clickfactor1);
            foreach (Attribute_2f entity in returnlist)
            {
                if (p != 0)
                {
                    if (y == returnlist.Count())
                    {

                        dt = new DataTable(facc);
                        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
                        dt.Columns.Add("Market Value");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Interest Accrued");
                        dt.Columns.Add("GainLoss");
                        dt.Columns.Add("CashFlow");
                        dt.Columns.Add("EOP Weightage");
                        dt.Columns.Add("BOP Weightage");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Return");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Cum_Return");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Contribution");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Cum_contribution");
                        dt.Columns.Add("annualised");
                        dt.Columns.Add("premarket");
                        dt.Columns.Add("preinterest");
                        dt.Columns.Add("inflow");
                        dt.Columns.Add("gainlost");
                        y = 0;
                    }
                }
                DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
                //foreach of your properties
                row1["Date"] = entity.getDate().Substring(0, 4) + "/" + entity.getDate().Substring(4, 2) + "/" + entity.getDate().Substring(6, 2);
                row1["Market Value"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getMarketValue());
                row1["Interest Accrued"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getIntAccrued());
                row1["CashFlow"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getinoutflow());
                row1["GainLoss"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getGainLoss());
                row1["EOP Weightage"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getWeightage());
                row1["BOP Weightage"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getdop_weightage_gross());
                row1["Return"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getAttrReturn() - 1);
                row1["Contribution"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getContribution());
                row1["premarket"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getpmarketValue());
                row1["preinterest"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getPintAccrued());
                row1["inflow"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getinoutflow());
                row1["gainlost"] = String.Format("{0:C}", entity.getGainLoss());
                row1["Cum_Return"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getCum_return() - 1);
                row1["BOP Weightage"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getweightage_gross());
                row1["annualised"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getannualised());
                row1["Cum_contribution"] = String.Format("{0:P2}", entity.getCum_contribution());
                y = y + 1;                        
                dt.Rows.Add(row1);
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            y = 0;
        }

       //excel workbook
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            string FileName = fromYear.ToString() + fromMonth.ToString() + "-" + toYear.ToString() + toMonth.ToString() + "(" + cbattr.ToString() + ")" + ".xlsx";

            if (FileName.Contains("cc.[AssetClsname]"))
            {
                FileName = FileName.Replace("cc.[AssetClsname]", "AssetClsname");
            }
            if (FileName.Contains("cc.[AssetClsname_IMA]"))
            {
                FileName = FileName.Replace("cc.[AssetClsname_IMA]", "AssetClsname_IMA");
            }
            if (FileName.Contains(","))
            {
                FileName = FileName.Replace(",", " ");

                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);
                    ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dt);
                    ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

                    ws.Tables.FirstOrDefault().ShowAutoFilter = false;
                    ws.Clear(XLClearOptions.Formats);             
                }
                p++;
                wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);

                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some images:

[[image: Table format]]

[[image: Moving multiple worksheets error]]

Comment: That's a pretty lengthy code dump. Could you perhaps reduce it to the most salient parts? (i.e. make a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338164/remove-all-formatting-of-the-table-created-from-inserttable-method-in-closedxml